# Building a program in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, security, tls

I am a Windows user but I need to use a Linux tool. I am using Ubuntu. The tool's website [here](https://github.com/prbinu/tls-scan) provided a file named: `build-x86-64.sh` which I installed it. It then says all what you need is to run: `% ./build-x86-64.sh`. I tried `sudo ./build-x86-64.sh`. However, I get this error from Linux:

```
sudo: ./build-x86-64.sh: command not found
```

Note that I am in the right directory where I saved the `.sh` file. I also installed all the per-requisites:

```
autoconf
automake
libtool
pkg-config
gcc
```

Please, can you point to me what's wrong?

Comment: Did you change to the repo's directory first?

Comment: Where should the repo. be installed?

Comment: The website says: `All you need is build-x86-64.sh. This script pulls tls-scan, its dependent packages` so I actually did not download the repo. in my local machine. See [link](https://github.com/prbinu/tls-scan).

Comment: Did you change the permission of the file to executable?

Comment: No. I just downloaded the `.sh` and tried to run it. If there are any other steps I should do, please list them to me.

Comment: `chmod +x build-x86-64.sh` and then run it `./build-x86-64.sh`

Comment: Can you help in this? `./build-x86-64.sh: 8: ./build-x86-64.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected`. I checked the code, I do not see where the error is? there is not newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my experience with installation.

first of all decide where you want the installation to take place ( for testing I used my /tmp directory  but you could use /opt or /usr for example.)

once inside the chosen dir, use the following command.

```
git clone https://github.com/prbinu/tls-scan.git
```

(this left me with /tmp/tls-scan/)

```
cd /tmp/tls-scan
sudo bash -vvv ./build-x86-64.sh
```

installation was fine for me. I hope it helps you, if you need anything further, please post the full output from the bash -vvv command and we can try to figure out whats going wrong. See you

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-built binary if that helps:
https://github.com/prbinu/tls-scan/releases/tag/0.1.9

Comment: Putting links does not provide an answer, Please extract useful content from the link and write here as an answer that can solve the OP. It would save you from downvotes.